# Terraform + Route53 - manage existing record

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I have a production environment that is configured to have a domain name that points to a load-balancer. This is already working, and it was configured using Route53.

I am using Terraform to deploy the infrastructure, including the Route53 record.

The Route53 record was set **manually**.

I would like for Terraform to manage the Route53 record in subsequent deployments. However, when I run an update to update the infrastructure and include the Route53 record, I get this error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

 * module.asg.aws_route53_record.www: 1 error(s) occurred:

 * aws_route53_record.www: [ERR]: Error building changeset: 
    InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create a resource record set
    [name='foo.com.', type='A'] but it already exists]
```

Well, at first, this error makes sense, because the resource already exists. But, given this, **how can I overcome this issue without causing downtime?**

I've tried to manually edit the state file to include the route53 record, but that failed with the same error...

I'm happy to provide more information if necessary. Any suggestions that you might have are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error when you ran `terraform import ...` to add the record to your state file and also show the plan output?

Answer (score 7):

You can use terraform import to import the existing Route53 resource into your current terraform infrastructure. Here are the steps:

1. Init terraform with your desire workspace via terraform init.
2. Define your aws_route53_record exactly the same as the existing resource that you have

   resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
   // your code here
   }
3. Import the desired resource

terraform import aws_route53_record.www ZONEID_RECORDNAME_TYPE_SET-IDENTIFIER

For example:

terraform import aws_route53_record.www Z4KAPRWWNC7JR_dev.example.com_CNAME

After import successfully, this will save the state of the existing resource.

4. Do terraform plan to check the resource
5. You now can update to your existing resource

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the record into your Terraform state with the `terraform import` command. **You should not edit the state manually!**

See the resource [Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#import) for additional information on how to import the record.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. `terraform import` simply edits the state file (handling locking the state during it if you have state locking enabled) so as long as you edit it by hand properly then it's fine and isn't the source of this error.

Comment: The truth is I am not doing terraform import. I only do terraform init, plan and apply.
Do you think that, given that I don't import, it's not getting the latest manual changes on the state file? @ydaetskcoR
I will edit the question tomorrow morning to include the output of the plan, and I will also look into the terraform import command

Comment: Yes, `terraform import` is what OP is looking for.

Comment: I looked into `terraform import` and this proved to be a nightmare. Apparently, there are some serious problems with terraform import when you have providers that use variables instead of hard-coded values. In the end, to avoid downtime and fix the issue, we ended up redirecting the traffic and recreating the infrastructure from scratch. It wasn't fun, but was simpler than using `terraform import`....

Comment: +1. I waded through 4 pages of Google results unsuccessfully looking for a real example of "terraform import" on route53 records. If this were a real site with traffic, I advise _not_ trying to make this work with terraform (just automate it with something else). In my case it was a toy personal site with no traffic so I bit the bullet and rebuilt DNS in TF (note: you'll be issued new NS and have to update your domreg also).

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it here for new visitors.

In the later versions of aws provider(~3.10), they offer an argument `allow_overwrite` defaults to false.
No need to edit state file (not recommended) or do terraform import.

> allow_overwrite - (Optional) Allow creation of this record in Terraform to overwrite an existing record, if any. This does not affect the ability to update the record in Terraform and does not prevent other resources within Terraform or manual Route 53 changes outside Terraform from overwriting this record. false by default. This configuration is not recommended for most environments.

from: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_record#allow_overwrite

Comment: I want to update an `A` record to `CNAME` record but allow_overwrite=true 
did not help me, 
Is there anything more to it ?

Comment: We can't update a record from type A to CNAME, without deletion. That's not supported by AWS or generally any DNS providers. 
However, the change isn't going to cause any downtime, since the DNS value remains same. So, go ahead with destroy and create via terraform.